# How to resolve build error in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have one text box control on aspx page in my .net application.

and in code behind on page load event i wrote:

```
txt.Text = "Sample"
```

Now if build website on system [ windows XP ] it build properly but  on system [ Windows 7 Enterprise ] it showing following error:

" Name 'txt' is not declared "

[image]

What would be the reason.Is that environment specific problem.I am using VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had issues similar to this before, usually caused by the designer not updating after adding new control to the page. to fix i would recommend

1. taking the textbox with id of txt
   out of the page.
2. then save the
   page.
3. now close the aspx page.
4. re open the aspx again
5. place textbox control with id txt back onto the
   page again and save.

think it should work now.

Comment: Its annoying how the designer gets out of sync sometimes.I seem to get less of these issues when I drag n drop things onto the designer surface than when I hand code them in. Unfortunately, 99% of the time I hand code my markup.